# Can't run a test class on a class with ConnectApi.ManagedTopics as an Internal user OR as a Community user

Tags: lightning-web-components, unit-test, community, connect-api

I have an LWC which displays as a collapsible menu on an Experience Cloud Site. It's in a scratch org, and I'd like to deploy to production. The LWC is using a class that uses `ConnectApi.ManagedTopics` to get the Topic information. I've written a test class, but can't figure out a way to run it for this reason:

When I run it in system mode, I get this error: "Managed Topics is
not available in Internal Community".

When I use System.runAs to run the test as a Community Guest User, I
get this error: "Community Guest users are not supported in the
default org."

How can I run this test class?

Test Class:

```
public class ConnectTopicCatalogController_Test {
    @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) static void testConnectTopicCatalogCollection(){
        TestKaModel.initData();
        User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Community User'];
        System.runAs(u){
            Test.startTest();
            String result = ConnectTopicCatalogController.ConnectTopicCatalogCollection();
            Test.stopTest();
            System.Debug(result);
            System.Assert(result.contains(TestKaModel.article1.Title));
            System.Assert(result.contains(TestKaModel.article2.Title));
            System.Assert(result.contains(TestKaModel.subsubtopic.Name));
            System.Assert(result.contains(TestKaModel.subtopic.Name));
            System.Assert(result.contains(TestKaModel.topic.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
  
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String ConnectTopicCatalogCollection(){
        try
        {
            String ntwrkId = Network.getNetworkId();
            ConnectApi.ManagedTopicCollection managedTopic =
                ConnectApi.ManagedTopics.getManagedTopics(
                    ntwrkId, ConnectApi.ManagedTopicType.Navigational,3
                );
            Set<Id> topicsSet = new Set<Id>();
            Set<Id> subTopicsSet = new Set<Id>();
            Set<Id> subSubTopicsSet = new Set<Id>();
            //Filling up a map of all topics, subtopics and sub-subtopics
            Map<TopicDetails, Map<TopicDetails, List<TopicDetails>>> childGrandChildTopicsMap = new Map<TopicDetails, Map<TopicDetails, List<TopicDetails>>>();
            for(ConnectApi.ManagedTopic parent :managedTopic.managedTopics){
                topicsSet.add((parent.Topic.Id));
                Map<TopicDetails, List<TopicDetails>> grandChildTopicsListMap = new  Map<TopicDetails, List<TopicDetails>>();
                for(ConnectApi.ManagedTopic childTopic : parent.children){
                    subTopicsSet.add(childTopic.Topic.Id);
                    List<TopicDetails> grandChildTopicslist = new List<TopicDetails>();
                    for(ConnectApi.ManagedTopic grandChildTopic : childTopic.children){
                        subSubTopicsSet.add((grandChildTopic.Topic.Id));
                        grandChildTopicslist.add(new TopicDetails(grandChildTopic.Topic.Id, grandChildTopic.Topic.Name));
                    }
                    grandChildTopicslistMap.put(new TopicDetails(childTopic.Topic.Id, childTopic.Topic.Name), grandChildTopicslist);
                }
                childGrandChildTopicsMap.put(new TopicDetails(parent.Topic.Id, parent.Topic.Name), grandChildTopicslistMap);   
            }          
            System.Debug('Topics Set: ' + topicsSet);
            System.Debug('Sub Topics Set: ' + subTopicsSet);
            System.Debug('Sub Sub Topics Set: ' + subSubTopicsSet);
  
            ConnectApi.Community comm = ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunity(ntwrkId);
            List<TreeWrapper> jsonArr = new List<TreeWrapper>();
            Map<Id, Knowledge__kav> topicArticleMap = new Map<Id, Knowledge__kav>();
            topicArticleMap = getTopicArticleMap(topicsSet);
            System.debug('TopicArticleMap; ' + topicArticleMap);
            Map<Id, Knowledge__kav> subTopicArticleMap = new Map<Id, Knowledge__kav>();
            subTopicArticleMap = getTopicArticleMap(subTopicsSet);
            System.debug('SubTopicArticleMap; ' + subTopicArticleMap);
            Map<Id, Knowledge__kav> subSubTopicArticleMap = new Map<Id, Knowledge__kav>();
            subSubTopicArticleMap = getTopicArticleMap(subSubTopicsSet);
            System.debug('SubSubTopicArticleMap; ' + subSubTopicArticleMap);
            System.debug('ChildGrandChildTopicsMapKeyset: ' + childGrandChildTopicsMap.keyset());
            for(TopicDetails parent : childGrandChildTopicsMap.keyset()){
                TreeWrapper tWrapper = new TreeWrapper();
                List<Item> itemsUnderTopic = new List<Item>();
                Item itemUnderTopic;
                tWrapper.label = parent.name;
                tWrapper.name = parent.name;
                tWrapper.href = comm.siteUrl+'/s/topic/'+parent.id+'/'+parent.name;
                tWrapper.expanded = True;
                List<Knowledge__kav> articlesUnderTopic = new List<Knowledge__kav>();
                for(Id taId : topicArticleMap.keyset()){
                    if(taId == parent.Id){
                        articlesUnderTopic.add(topicArticleMap.get(taId));
                    }
                }
                for (Knowledge__kav a: articlesUnderTopic){
                    itemUnderTopic = new Item();
                    itemUnderTopic.label = a.title;
                    itemUnderTopic.name = a.title;
                    itemUnderTopic.href = comm.siteUrl+'/s/topic/'+a.urlName;
                    itemsUnderTopic.add(itemUnderTopic);
                }
                System.debug('ChildGrandChildTopicsMap.get(parent).Keyset: ' + childGrandChildTopicsMap.get(parent).keyset());
                for(TopicDetails child : childGrandChildTopicsMap.get(parent).keyset()){
                    Item subTopic = new Item();
                    List<Item> itemsUnderSubTopic = new List<Item>();
                    Item itemUnderSubTopic;
                    subTopic.label = child.name;
                    subTopic.name = child.name;
                    subTopic.href = comm.siteUrl+'/s/topic/'+child.id+'/'+child.name;
                    subTopic.expanded = false;
                    itemsUnderTopic.add(subTopic);
                    List<Knowledge__kav> articlesUnderSubTopic = new List<Knowledge__kav>();
                    for(Id staId : subTopicArticleMap.keyset()){
                        if(staId == child.Id){
                            articlesUnderSubTopic.add(subTopicArticleMap.get(staId));
                        }
                    }
                    for (Knowledge__kav a: articlesUnderSubTopic){
                        itemUnderSubTopic = new Item();
                        itemUnderSubTopic.label = a.title;
                        itemUnderSubTopic.name = a.title;
                        itemUnderSubTopic.href = comm.siteUrl+'/s/topic/'+a.urlName;
                        itemsUnderSubTopic.add(itemUnderSubTopic);
                    }
                    System.debug('ChildGrandChildTopicsMap.get(parent).Keyset: ' + childGrandChildTopicsMap.get(parent).get(child));
                    for(TopicDetails grandChild : childGrandChildTopicsMap.get(parent).get(child)){
                        Item subSubTopic = new Item();
                        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
                        Item item;
                        subSubTopic.label = grandChild.name;
                        subSubTopic.name = grandChild.name;
                        subSubTopic.href = comm.siteUrl+'/s/topic/'+grandChild.id+'/'+grandChild.name;
                        subSubTopic.expanded = false;
                        itemsUnderSubTopic.add(subSubTopic);
                        List<Knowledge__kav> articlesUnderSubSubTopic = new List<Knowledge__kav>();
                        for(Id sstaId : subSubTopicArticleMap.keyset()){
                            if(sstaId == grandChild.Id){
                                articlesUnderSubSubTopic.add(subSubTopicArticleMap.get(sstaId));
                            }
                        }
                        for (Knowledge__kav a: articlesUnderSubSubTopic){
                            item = new Item();
                            item.label = a.title;
                            item.name = a.title;
                            item.href = comm.siteUrl+'/s/topic/'+a.urlName;
                            items.add(item);
                        }
                    subSubTopic.items = items;                
                    }
                subTopic.items = itemsUnderSubTopic;
                }
            tWrapper.items = itemsUnderTopic;
            jsonArr.add(tWrapper);
            }
           
            String jsonBody = JSON.serializePretty(jsonArr);
            System.debug('jsonBody: ' + jsonBody);
            return jsonBody;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.debug('Error in ConnectTopicCatalogController: ' + ex.getMessage());
            System.debug(ex.getStackTraceString());
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
   
    public class Item {
        public String label;
        public String name;
        public String href;
        public Boolean expanded;
        public List<Item> items;
    }
  
    public class TreeWrapper{
        public String label;
        public String name;
        public String href;
        public Boolean expanded;
        public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    }
   
    public class TopicDetails{
        public String id;
        public String name;
       
        public TopicDetails(String id, String name){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    public static Map<Id, Knowledge__kav> getTopicArticleMap (Set<Id> topicIds){
        System.debug('In the function');
        System.debug('TopicIds: ' + topicIds);
        //Map of all ids and articles
        Map<Id, Knowledge__kav> articleMap = new Map<Id, Knowledge__kav>([SELECT Id, Title, UrlName FROM Knowledge__kav]);
        System.debug('ArticleMap: '+ articleMap);
        //Map of Topics, TopicAssignments, ArticleIds
        List<TopicAssignment> topicAssignmentList = new List<TopicAssignment>([SELECT Id, TopicId, EntityId FROM TopicAssignment WHERE TopicId IN :topicIds LIMIT 1000]);
        System.debug('TopicAssignmentList: ' + topicAssignmentList);
        //Map of Topic Ids with Articles
        Map<Id, Knowledge__kav> topicArticleMap = new Map<Id, Knowledge__kav>();
        for(TopicAssignment ta : topicAssignmentList){
           topicArticleMap.put(ta.topicId, articleMap.get(ta.EntityId));
        }
        System.debug('TopicArticleMap: ' + topicArticleMap);
        return topicArticleMap;
    }
   
 }
```

Comment: Try the approach mentioned in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327977/how-to-create-a-test-for-the-managedtopic/328053#328053

Comment: Thank you @Swetha. I do have a community set up on my scratch org. I tried System.runAs(siteGuestUser), but got the error that "Community Guest users are not supported in the default org"

Comment: Can you check what does it show for Community ID in the test class adding a debug statement.Ensure it is not Null