# Test Class for ManagedTopic encountered error: "ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Managed Topics is not available in internal community"

Tags: apex, unit-test, community, salesforce1-app

I have an Apex class RecentArticlesController that has a method that returns a list of Navigational Managed Topics:

```
public without sharing class RecentArticlesController {
 @AuraEnabled
 public static List<ConnectApi.ManagedTopic> getManagedTopics(String recId) {
    ConnectAPI.ManagedTopicCollection mTopics = ConnectAPI.ManagedTopics.getManagedTopics(
        Network.getNetworkId(),
        ConnectApi.ManagedTopicType.Navigational,
        3
    );
    
    return mTopics.managedTopics;
 }
}
```

I'm trying to create a test for this method:

```
@isTest
public class ManagedTopicsTestClass {
@IsTest(SeeAllData=true) static void testGetManagedTopics() {
    User usr = [select id,Name from User where id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
    
    System.runAs(usr) {
        String topicName = 'Test topic';
        
        Topic topic = new Topic(Name = topicName);
        
        insert topic;
        
        ConnectApi.ManagedTopic managedTopic = ConnectApi.ManagedTopics.createManagedTopic(
            null,
            topic.Id,
            ConnectApi.ManagedTopicType.Navigational
        );
        
        List<ConnectApi.ManagedTopic> managedTopics = RecentArticlesController.getManagedTopics(null);
        
        System.assertEquals(1, managedTopics.size());
    }
}
}
```

But when running this test in a scratch org, I'm getting the following error:

```
ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Managed Topics is not available in internal community
```

As I understand, there is no way to create a Community dynamically in the test method.

What is the correct way to write this test?

Comment: Please see this similar post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327977/how-to-create-a-test-for-the-managedtopic/328053#328053

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your effort but I already found that post and it's not working on my end.

Comment: By 'not working' can you elaborate on where exactly are you stuck so I can suggest better? Have you ensured that the related Experience Cloud site exists before deploying managed topics?

Comment: Yes, managed topics are on the site and it is available, based on the post above, I am stuck because of the error encountered.